# Search with overlay entry in flutter

Tags: flutter, setstate

I am using an overlay entry which contains a listviewbuilder. Now that list is being filtered when user give an input. the issue is that when I filtered the list without overlay it works fine but when I user overlay the list is not filtered on input. it is filtered when i remove a value from user input.
Like I entered Dorm-G-01 but it will not show results of it if I remove 1 from it then it gives the result of Dorm-G-01. According to me setState is not changing upon input.

`

```
    import 'dart:async';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Address extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddressState createState() => _AddressState();
}

class _AddressState extends State<Address> {
  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();
  TextEditingController addressController = TextEditingController();
  late OverlayEntry _overlayEntry;
  List<String> _hostel = [];

  List<String> _filter = [];
  String serachText="";
  Timer? _debounce;
  final LayerLink _layerLink = LayerLink();
  void getAddress() {
    final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Services').snapshots();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _hostel.add('Dorm-G-01');
    _hostel.add('Dorm-G-02');
    _hostel.add('Dorm-G-03');
    _hostel.add('Dorm-G-04');
    _hostel.add('Dorm-G-05');
    _hostel.add('Dorm-G-06');
    _hostel.add('Dorm-G-07');


    // _filter = _hostel;

    addressController.addListener(_onSerachChanged);
    _focusNode.addListener(() {
      if (_focusNode.hasFocus) {
        this._overlayEntry = this._createOverlayEntry();
          Overlay.of(context)!.insert(this._overlayEntry);
      } else {
        this._overlayEntry.remove();
      }
    });
  }

  OverlayEntry _createOverlayEntry() {
    final renderBox = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    var size = renderBox.size;
    final offset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    return OverlayEntry(
        builder: (context) => Positioned(
              left: offset.dx,
              top: offset.dy,
              bottom: offset.dy,
              width: size.width,
              child: CompositedTransformFollower(
                link: this._layerLink,
                showWhenUnlinked: false,
                offset: Offset(0.0, size.height + 5.0),
                child: Material(
                  elevation: 4.0,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      itemCount: _filter.length,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          tileColor: Colors.grey.shade300,
                          title: Text(_filter[index].toString()),
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              addressController.text = _filter[index];
                              _focusNode.unfocus();
                            });
                          },
                        );
                      }),
                ),
              ),
            ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CompositedTransformTarget(
      link: this._layerLink,
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: addressController,
        focusNode: this._focusNode,
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Address'),
      ),
    );
  }
  //on serach changed

  _onSerachChanged() {
    if(_debounce?.isActive ?? false) _debounce!.cancel();
    _debounce = Timer(
      const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
          () {
            _filter = _hostel;
          setState(() {
            _filter=_filter
                .where((item) => item
                .toString()
                .replaceAll(RegExp(r'[^\w\\s]+'), '')
                .toLowerCase()
                .contains(addressController.text
                .toString()
                .replaceAll(RegExp(r'[^\w\\s]+'), '')
                .toLowerCase()))
                .toList();
          });
      },
    );
  } //onSerachChanged

  @override
  void dispose() {
    addressController.removeListener(_onSerachChanged);
    addressController.dispose();
    _debounce!.cancel();

    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by just passing the filtration method inside textformfiled->onchanged

```
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CompositedTransformTarget(
      link: this._layerLink,
      child: TextFormField(

        controller: addressController,
        focusNode: this._focusNode,
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Address'),
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            _filter = _hostel.where((hostel) => hostel.toLowerCase().replaceAll(RegExp(r'[^\w\\s]+'), '').contains(value.toLowerCase().replaceAll(RegExp(r'[^\w\\s]+'), ''))).toList();
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```